# ReDim Preserve in For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know what I am doing wrong as the code below is able to `ReDim Preserve` the first iteration but not the second.

```
Dim inj0() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim pos As Integer

'Find the last used column in a Row
Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

c = 0
For i = 1 To LastCol
    pos = InStr(Cells(2, i), "80")
    If pos = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve inj0(c, 2)
        inj0(0, 1) = "80"
        Set Rng = Cells(2, i)
        inj0(c, 2) = Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        inj0(c, 0) = Rng.Offset(3, 0).Value
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Where do you get errors?

Comment: At `ReDim Preserve inj0(c, 2)` it says subscript out of range

Comment: You can only `ReDim preserve` the _last_ dimension of an array.  From online help _If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReDim Preserve "Subscript Out of Range"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393123/redim-preserve-subscript-out-of-range)

Comment: One optimization I'd consider here. Avoid using Redim Preserve, it is a costly operation. Instead, determine how many entries are going to be needed first then define the size, then fill the array. Something like doing a CountIf first to determine how many entries are needed would be better, especially if there is going to be a lot of data added to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the code as follows:

```
c = 0
ReDim inj0(2, 0)
inj0(1, 0) = "80"
For i = 1 To LastCol
    pos = InStr(Cells(2, i), "80")
    If pos = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve inj0(2, c)
        Set Rng = Cells(2, i)
        inj0(2, c) = Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        inj0(0, c) = Rng.Offset(3, 0).Value
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next
```

If you need the dimensions to be swapped, finally you can [apply `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx).