# Redimensioning an array within an Excel VBA function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to write a function that takes an array as input, does some manipulations to it - among others, redimensioning it by adding an additional row - and then outputs the modified array. However, when I try to redim the array, I get an error `"Subscript out of range"`.

To illustrate my problem, I have created a simplified coding framework, with one function...:

```
Function funcTestFunction(Number As Integer, Arr As Variant)

ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Number, 0 To 4)
funcTestFunction = Arr

End Function
```

... and a subroutine:

```
Sub subTestSubroutine()

Dim Number As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant

Number = 10
ReDim Arr(0 To Number - 1, 0 To 4)
Arr = funcTestFunction(Number, Arr)

End Sub
```

In this framework, when I execute `subTestSubroutine`, I get a `"Subscript out of range"` error, which is located at the `ReDim` line in function `funcTestFunction`.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

---

**Edit #1:**

Even the following code does not work:

```
Sub subTestSubroutine()

Dim Number As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant

Number = 10
ReDim Arr(0 To Number - 1, 0 To 4)
ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Number, 0 To 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: There may be other issues but you can only redim the last dimension of an array.

Comment: Well, I guess I have my answer... Didn't know.

Comment: See here for possible alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393123/redim-preserve-subscript-out-of-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a comment if I could...

One thing I did in this situation was use `Application.Transpose`. I wanted to add more rows to my 2D array, but you can really only add more columns with `Redim Preserve`. So you can transpose it once, add the number of columns, and then transpose it back.

```
transposeArr = Application.Transpose(Arr)
ReDim Preserve transposeArr(0 To 4, 0 To number)
funcTestFunction = Application.Transpose(transposeArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by resizing **Arr ()** to *Number-1* in ***subTestSubroutine*** and you are sending it *Number* in ***funcTestFunction***.

Try with this code should work:

```
Function funcTestFunction (Number As Integer, Arr As Variant)

  ReDim Preserve Arr (0 To Number - 1, 0 To 4)
  FuncTestFunction = Arr

End Function
```

Hope this can help!